# powershell script to find system Memory and CPU Usage for every 1 hr interval and auto update same in excel Rows

Tags: excel, powershell

I am new to powershell, kindly help. i need to create a powershell script to find system Memory and CPU Usage of servers for every 1 hr interval and  auto update same in excel rows with date and time in the same excel sheet so that i can calculate the average usage report for every day.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are a beginner to Powershell, there are several resources below, to help you along your way.

What you need is WMI, or [Windows Management Instrumentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The link may be too complicated for beginners, so the "tl dr" version is:

- allows you to get fine-grained data on specific processes running on your (or a remote) system
- allows you to perform administrative tasks

The class you will primarily work with is called [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
This class provides raw data regarding system and application processes.

Incidentally, the information provided by this class is also the same as what you will see in Perfmon, Windows Task Manager etc (they just prettify the raw data).

From the point-of-view of the above class, though, the terms "System Memory" and CPU Usage are a bit too ambiguous. Windows has several fine-grained concepts that deal with "System Memory" and "CPU Usage" - for example, there's PercentProcessorTime, PercentUserTime, PercentPrivilegedTime.

Once you figure out exactly what metric you want to gather, you can modify the code below to do what you need. The example below gathers PercentProcessorTime for a specific process (the "Powershell" process).

```
get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | ? { $_.name -eq 'powershell' } | select name, PercentProcessorTime
```

More info on the above command:

- [get-wmiobject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx) accesses WMI
- `| $_.name -eq powershell` filters the results of `get-wmiobject` by all results that contain name powershell.
- | `select` selects specific properties out of the result.

Comment: I need present processor time and present ram usage of the system and i need that to export to same excel data sheet. row wise. please help

Comment: It is expected that you would do some research of your own when asking a question here ([see StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ) . Have you tried reading Powershell and Microsoft TechNet documentation, for example?

Comment: i am almost done in making a script for updating the memory and CPU, kindly guide me how to import the same in excel for each 10 sec interval, code:
while ($true) {
     [int]$date = get-date -Uformat %s
     $exportlocation = New-Item -type file -path "c:\$date.csv"
     Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" | % {$_} | Out-File $exportlocation
     start-sleep -s 5
}

Comment: It looks like you are nearly there. But what's `| % {$} ` for? 
If you remove that, and change the sleep-time to 10-seconds, you have the processor time.

Comment: I executed the code as below : `($true) { [int]$date = get-date -Uformat %s $exportlocation = New-Item -type file -path "c:\sys-report.csv" Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(Total)\% Processor Time" | Out-File $exportlocation start-sleep -s 10 }` but i need to update the reports in the same excel "sys-report" row wise, and also i need to add the Memory allocated for each system, and top application running in process

Comment: Perhaps you can figure out the memory part yourself :) And I believe you can also figure out how to update the reports row-wise.